# Property [customInput] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-many, belongs-to

I have 2 models linked with each other: Link and Entries.
Inside my entries table I made a foreignId called link_id.

Entry model:

```
class Entry extends Model
{

use HasFactory;

protected $guarded = [];

protected $table = 'entries';

public function link() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Link::class);
}
```

Link model:

```
class Link extends Model

{

use HasFactory;
use Uuids;

protected $guarded = [];

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function entries() {
    return $this->hasMany(Entry::class);
}
```

When a visitor visits the link an entry is made.
The link contains some values, like a title etc.

Now I also made an admin panel where I can upload data to a 'customInput' field in the database as a string.
I just don't know how to get that data because when I try to use $link->entries->customInput, Laravel returns this error: Property [customInput] does not exist on this collection instance.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$link->entries` is a collection, so you need a loop to get the value from this collection :

```
@foreach($link->entries as $data)
   {{ $data->customInput }}
@endforeach
```